# Determine if points are visible

Tags: c++, line, linear-algebra, points

I am trying to figure out whether a set of points is visible to another point. I have a geometry mesh and an observation point(red dot on image). The mesh is broken up into line segments, each with a center (blue arrows). I need to determine if the observation point can see the center of the line segments without any of the other line segments being in between.

The method I have been following is trying to calculate a line perpendicular to the line between the observation point and each of the centers. Then projecting each of the line segments onto this line and checking if the center I am concerned with is in between the start and end point of a projected line segment. I either get everything is visible or invisible to the observation point.

I am using this as [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159603/linear-transformation-for-projection-of-a-point-on-a-line)

My question has two parts. Firstly, I cant figure out why this isn't working and secondly is there a better way to do this?

```
bool projectPointOntoLine(point observation, vector<segment> segments, int currentIndex){

point currentPoint = segments[currentIndex].getCenter();

double dx = observation.getX() - currentPoint.getX();
double dy = observation.getY() - currentPoint.getY();

double m = -dy/dx;
double mm = m*m;

double newX = calculateNewX(currentPoint.getX(), currentPoint.getY(), m, mm);
double newY = calculateNewY(currentPoint.getX(), currentPoint.getY(), m, mm);

long double minDist = sqrt((currentPoint.getX() - observation.getX())*(currentPoint.getX() - observation.getX()) + (currentPoint.getY() - observation.getY())*(currentPoint.getY() - observation.getY()));

bool visible = true;

for(unsigned ii = 0; ii < segments.size(); ii++){
    if(ii != currentIndex){

        point mid = segments[ii].getStart();

        long double dist = sqrt((mid.getX() - observation.getX())*(mid.getX() - observation.getX()) + (mid.getY() - observation.getY())*(mid.getY() - observation.getY()));

        if(dist < minDist) {

            point start = segments[ii].getStart();
            point end = segments[ii].getEnd();

            double newStartX = calculateNewX(start.getX(), start.getY(), m, mm);
            double newStartY = calculateNewY(start.getX(), start.getY(), m, mm);

            double newEndX = calculateNewX(end.getX(), end.getY(), m, mm);
            double newEndY = calculateNewY(end.getX(), end.getY(), m, mm);

            if ((newX >= newStartX && newEndX >= newX)){// && (newY >= newStartY && newEndY >= newY)) {
                visible = false;
            }
            else if ((newX >= newEndX && newStartX >= newX)){//} && (newY >= newEndY && newStartY >= newY)) {
                visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
}

return visible;
}

double calculateNewX(double x, double y, double gradient, double gradientSquared){
return (1/(1 + gradientSquared))*(x) + (gradient/(1 + gradientSquared))*(y);
}

double calculateNewY(double x, double y, double gradient, double gradientSquared){
return (gradient/(1 + gradientSquared))*(x) + (gradientSquared/(1 + gradientSquared))*(y);
}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

Which is only half of the shadowing.

Comment: What do `calculateNewX` and `calculateNewY` do? For readability consider merging them into a single function which takes a `point` and returns a `point`. What's the purpose of `scale`? Scaling seems to factor out when calculating `m`.

Comment: Sorry about that. The scaling was when I was trying something earlier. I've updated the code section now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is here:

```
    if((newX > newStartX && newEndX > newX) && (newY > newStartY && newEndY > newY)){
        visible = false;
    }
```

You presume that `newStartX` is always less than `newEndX` (same with `Y`). This is not necessarily the case. Depending on mutual orientation of the segment and the line to project on, the endpoints may flip.

Comment: Would I then just need to add and extra check if the `originalStartX` is is less than the `originalEndX` otherwise swap the points around and do the same for the y coordinates?